# At what time in the day does a scratch org expire?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

At what point in the day does a scratch org expire? I am working on a scratch org that expires today (3/11) and am still able to log and run commands against it.

Should I anticipate being able to access until midnight tonight?

Comment: What does the `CreatedDate` timestamp show? I would assume it runs on a 24 hour clock and should be available until the same timestamp as in `CreatedDate` on the `ExpirationDate`. Can you check that if you are able to login past the timestamp of created date as well?

Comment: I'd assume there is a background process (or processes) that is cleaning up the expired orgs. This would be similar to the "Sweeper" that removes expired developer edition orgs, only much more frequently. Whenever it does run it will collect anything with a `ScratchOrgInfo.ExpirationDate` in the past. Exactly when it runs likely depends on the volume of scratch orgs it needs to work through.

Comment: Thank you - no timestamp on the 'expiration tag'. The created date does though have a time stamp. you can also view this information by running the sfdx force:org:display --verbose -u scratchorg. Unfortunately i lost track of time in the day was unable to really see at what time int he day it expired. I'll keep an eye out and update if I come up with anything.

Comment: output of sfdx force:org:display --verbose -u scratchorg .                     
 Access Token     
Alias            shapeorg
Client Id        SalesforceDevelopmentExperience
Created By       luigi
Created Date     2019-03-14T12:32:47.000+0000
Dev Hub Id       luigi
Expiration Date  2019-04-06
Id              
Instance Url     https://flow-saas-3431.cs65.my.salesforce.com/
Org Name       
Sfdx Auth Url    
Status           Active
Username         @example.com